# Windows Phone PhoneGap app back button issue

Tags: c#, javascript, css, cordova, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone PhoneGap app. When clicking hardware back button, It is going to the previous page using history.go(-1); But when I am in initial page and click the back button It is navigating to the same page instead of killing the application. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure back button you can use these functions:

```
// for exit app
navigator.app.exitApp();

// for back hsitory use
navigator.app.backHistory()
```

complete code :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(e){
       if($.mobile.activePage.is('#home')){
           e.preventDefault();
           navigator.app.exitApp();
       }
       else {
           navigator.app.backHistory()
       }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: this code works in windows phone 7. But, in windows phone 8, the error "Unable to get property 'exitApp' of undefined or null reference" comes. could u suggest me how to resolve this?

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, this code doesn't work in Windows Phone 8. somebody please help

Comment: Oh sorry for windows 8 maybe need additional configuration :),
but i never use in windows 8 app :D

Answer (score 1):

Above answer may work with windows phone 7 but it is not working with windows phone 8.1 . For override back-button in windows phone 8.1 we can use `WinJS` api.

Bind back button event on device ready.

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady(){
   //check if WinJS api is available or not
   if(WinJS){
      WinJS.Application.onbackclick = function (e) {
         //write your code here
         return true; // you must return true otherwise it will close app.
     }
   }
}
```